# Kendo UI Grid not working properly in Wicket wizards

Tags: wicket, kendo-ui-grid

I am using Wicket with Wicket Kendo UI library.

I have a wizard containing a Kendo Grid in one of its steps. When I reach this step the table shows up alright, but when I move to the next step and then return back, sometimes a problem occurs: table data is not shown in the table and what I see is the empty table and a splash screen rolling indefinitely.

Inspecting the network I found out that there are two requests when showing the step with the table: one containing the xml with the table markup and js, and the other with json data containing table rows. Both requests finish successfully but somehow the table is unable to pick up the data for its rows from the second one.

This problem doesn't occur every time, sometimes the table picks up its data correcly.

Trying to isolate the problem I have found out the following: Wicket wizards use the method MarkupContainer.replace(Component child) when switching between step, so the problem can be reproduced without wizards. All you need to do is to replace the table on a page with something else and then swap it back again.

Does anybody have any ideas why the table might behave in such odd fashion. Is it because the new markup kind of looses its link with the js-code which can't find where to put received data or something?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have found out where the problem was. When rendering the next step Wicket wizard replaces the markup of the previous step, right? Doing so results in removing the related cached data from the jquery cache ($.cache). It turns out that kendo grid uses that data and when the previous step is restored and the grid is rendered it can't find that data. So in my case the solution was to hide the table before moving to the next step, that way, when the grid is rendered it repopulated its cache data and everything worked fine.